# Media Queries Responsive Design

Tags: html, css

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

nav ul{
    transform: translateY(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
   transition: all .5s;
  }
 nav li{
    flex: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
  } 
  nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;   
  transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav label{display: block;}  
  nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1){
    background: #777; 
    color: #fff;
  }  

  #css-toggle-menu{
  float:right;
  margin: 10px;
  }

}




/*Desktop*/


@media (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
nav{

float:left; 
color:white;



}



nav ul li.active a {
 background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {

  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;

  }



nav ul li a:visited {
color:black;
text-decoration:none;   
}

}
```

```html
<header>
   <nav>
     <input type="checkbox" id="css-toggle-menu" name="css-toggle-menu"> 
     <ul class="main">
           <li><a class="space" href="">Home</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Programs</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Assignments</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Enroll</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Contact</a></li>

     </ul> 
     <label for="css-toggle-menu" id="css-toggle-menu"></label> 
   </nav>
</header>
```

With media queries I thought that when you set them up in tablet and desktop that once you reach those parameters that the other layout like tablet would go away when you were switching to desktop. However, I'm running into an issue where when I switch from tablet mode to desktop my nav bar from my mobile and tablet screens is brought to my desktop. On my desktop I just want a horizontal nav at the top of the page. I did not put any css to make it into the tablet nav bar so I do not know how to override this in desktop. I could really use some help with this in understanding this media queries issue. Thank you!

Here is a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ma28j5kd/
(I know the fiddle isn't pretty so I apologize in advance)

HTML:

```
<header>
   <nav>
     <input type="checkbox" id="css-toggle-menu" name="css-toggle-menu"> 
     <ul class="main">
           <li><a class="space" href="">Home</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Programs</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Assignments</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Enroll</a></li>
           <li><a class="space" href="">Contact</a></li>

     </ul> 
     <label for="css-toggle-menu" id="css-toggle-menu"></label> 
   </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

Tablet:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

nav ul{
    transform: translateY(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
   transition: all .5s;
  }
 nav li{
    flex: none; 
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
  } 
  nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;   
  transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav label{display: block;}  
  nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1){
    background: #777; 
    color: #fff;
  }  

  #css-toggle-menu{
  float:right;
  margin: 10px;
  }

}
```

Desktop:

```
@media (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
nav{

float:left; 
color:white;



}



nav ul li.active a {
 background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {

  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;

  }



nav ul li a:visited {
color:black;
text-decoration:none;   
}

}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] in the question itself. There are no media questions in the code you have put in the question. The example doesn't look very minimal either, you could probably replace it with a ruleset in each media query to show what you are trying to achieve. Also, please use [the built-in functionality for live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You have misunderstood how `@media`-queries work. `@media`-queries should override previous rules set in the CSS - if you want them to do complete takeover, you'll have to provide both min-width and max-width for when they should work, however, that is not their intent. You should never have to assing a media-query to "desktop" - desktop is your starting point, what you create first, then you create breakpoints for smaller screens when stuff on your screen starts overlapping, or get too small for good layout and userfriendliness. So you need to start from the beginning.